# MicroSD memory Card to USB

Tags: usb, memory, usb-device, interface, adapter

I am searching for a circuit or any technical documentation or interfacing IC to design the `MicroSD memory card to USB`. I am very well aware of Adapter available in market which serves the purpose. But I want to know what goes inside, if I can build it for my project.

I have found this 
[USB controller IC](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/USB2240)

The software part http://www.signal11.us/oss/m-stack/

Can i interface this with standard MicroSD memory card. Unable to find any circuit diagram for the same

Comment: You're searching for, or you want other people to do it for you? Show what you have done yourself, as indicated in http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: @EmbeddedGeek, you forgot to mention which host you are considering to interface with your USB-uSD bridge.

Answer (score 1):

The circuit diagram for this controller is right there in the [documentation of the eval board](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/DS50002298B-EVB-USB2240-IND_C-UsersManual-20140902.pdf), page 22. Basically, you need to connect all the `SD_*` pins of the controller to the corresponding pins of the SD card slot via 33 Ohm resistors, except for card presence signal `SD_nCD` pin which has to be connected directly.

Comment: How PC will detect the USB port? Drivers?

Comment: This particular chip is fully compliant to USB Mass Storage Class specification. No special driver is necessary to operate it, the device will look like a normal external storage device.