# MicroSD to USB adapter

Tags: usb, memory, sd, adapter

My goal is to make a *MicroSD to USB* adapter myself.

[With this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/252895/microsd-memory-card-to-usb), I saw that I can use a [`USB2240`](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/USB2240) controller chip to connect my µSD card to my computer.

[In this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N3TBreeBnpk), he is using a `1701 ic` which seems to be a voltage regulator and everything seems to work fine.

In that case, what are the benefits of a controller chip over just a simple voltage regulator?

Also, in the previous Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange question, the OP put a link about [M-Stack](https://web.archive.org/web/20160326184630/www.signal11.us/oss/m-stack/), do I need to install it on the `USB2240` controller chip to make it work and what is it exactly?

Sorry these questions might be stupid, I am still a beginner. Thanks.

Comment: Whatever that chip is, it isn't just a voltage regulator.

Comment: The benefit of using a USB controller is that it lets you connect over USB.  Without one, you can draw power from a USB port, but not access data.

Comment: Don't do this, it's pointless, buy it as there's no useful learning or feature to achieve here.  Pick projects that offer something you can't just buy.  Besides you havent asked a specifically answerable question.

Comment: @user1850479 In the video, the guy can access the µSD in his computer even though it seems to be only a voltage regulator.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I am limited in space for the adapter (more or less the size of the µSD) and such sizes are not commercially available (maybe they are but I didn't find them). As I am so much limited in space, I will not use a USB connector and will directly solder the wires to the main board.

Comment: @ufjyxnm7ux If USB works then he has a USB controller. Post a datasheet for the chips you're asking about.

Comment: @user1850479 The only info in the video is [1- 1701 i.c. ( you can get this from any old mp3 players)], a search on Google gives me information of voltage regulators but maybe there is a lot of parts named `1701`. If you say that it will not work if it's just a voltage regulator, I trust you. Initially I thought that maybe the controller inside the µSD will work to connect to the computer but that may be false.

Comment: @user1850479 Just a last question, do you need to install specific software on the USB controller or it will work out of the box? Thanks.

Comment: So desolder the connector from a commercial one, though as the smaller ones put the card practically inside the connector that's not going to help much.  Your question makes it clear you are not ready to tackle this project.

Comment: @ufjyxnm7ux  Simple ones probably come with all the needed software built in. 
 Depends on the part in question though.  Check the datasheet.

Comment: @ChrisStratton No offense but how people are supposed to learn when you tell them "you'r not good enough to do that"? We all need to start somewhere, fail, learn, then succeed. Telling someone "don't do that / it's pointless" is the worst advice you can give to someone. We learn with practice so we should try and maybe fail. It's not towards you but I just hate this kind of comments.

Comment: @user1850479 Thanks you for all your answers.

Comment: @ufjyxnm7ux it's not that all projects are pointless, it's that a project that is little more than a fixed function IC generally best sourced as a finished product is pointless.  Something that was a USB gizmo that needed MCU firmware could be a quite rewarding project, but that's not what an SD->USB adapter is.  Such a device is a pointless project because you cannot realistically build a better one than you can buy, other projects are not.  Developing a sense of where it is vs isn't worth putting effort is as important a part of it as any other.

Comment: @ChrisStratton "Developing a sense of where it is vs isn't worth putting effort ..." I agree, but to understand that, you first need some experience. Sure this project may not be worth the effort but right now from my own beginner perspective: I need such an adapter (and I think it's important to see a practical use when you start a new project), there's only one chip so it's still "simple" (compared to a lot of other electronic projects), the goal is not to have something better that commercial adapter I'm not a company with dozen on engineers working a chip. I just want to learn new things.

Comment: @ChrisStratton By the way, if you have some ideas / links of interesting projects to learn, please do not hesitate to share, it will be really helpful.

Comment: Cool project idea, but I'm not sure you know how to do it. You need some kind of  microcontroller at a minimum. This 1701 chip is obviously NOT a voltage regulator. It happens to have the same part number as a voltage regulator and it doesn't seem to have a datasheet since it's secret to Sony, so when you google it, you find the voltage regulator. But it still isn't one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before embarking on a project like uSD interface over USB, you need to understand/appreciate few things.

1. USB is a complex protocol, which has no direct relationship with multitude of SD cards protocols.
2. The 1701 IC is apparently a bridge between USB (likely FS, or maybe HS) protocol and uSD card. Looking at their "schematics", the IC uses the simplest initial SPI-like protocol to access uSD data.
3. To get access to uSD, the IC bridge implements complex data structures that represents USB Mass Storage Class (MSC). Without the MSC your PC will not understand data/control formats.
4. To bridge a uSD to MSC interface, the IC must first initialize the SD interface, and then evaluate uSD card capability and file structure. This requires lengthy serial data transfers on uSD side, and analysis of card responses. Remember, there are many types of uSD cards, of various sizes and write structures, and one never knows what kind of card you will insert. So the IC bridge must be intelligent enough to recognize the particular card.
5. All this functionality is hidden from you inside the IC, so there is not much you can learn, unless you put USB analyzer on USB end, and SD/MMC analyzer on the card's end.
6. I know nothing about "AB701" IC, but if you try USB2240, you will need a 24MHz crystal, couple of capacitors, you can find reference design files on MCHP site.
7. The USB2240 embeds a 8-bit microcontroller with advanced 80C51 architecture, which runs a code from internal flash memory, which is compiled from thousands of lines of C++ code, so the chip will discover identity of plugged uSD card, and built proper capability tables to report in accord with Mass Storage Class interface.
8. As you now can see, the youtube video is highly misleading, by hiding all the above technicalities.
9. You can certainly solder all 36 wires to the QFN36 IC with tiny 0.5 mm pitch, and, if done correctly, it might work. Better, you will need to design a PCB (say, using free tool from ExpressPCB), all in accord with manufacturer's recommendations, and you will have an interface to uSD card over USB port.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer and pointing where so much things. Thanks a lot.